# MySQL verify 10 minute increments in timestamps

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm working with a logfile that records data every 10 minutes. I'm trying to come up with a query that can verify that data was in fact saved every 10 minutes.

Here are some sample timestamps:

```
2008-01-01 00:00:00
2008-01-01 00:10:00
2008-01-01 00:20:00
2008-01-01 00:30:00
```

Any ideas on this? I'd give some SQL if I thought it could be improved to be correct but I don't have anything worth posting.

Comment: Are you trying to verify that the timestamps did not happen on non-10-minute increment marks?  Or that they happened on _every_ 10 minute mark? Or both?

Comment: Apologies, i'm trying to verify that they happened on 10-minute increment marks, just like the samples. I'm not checking for anything else. Thanks. Just curious, why did you delete the last part of my question. Should I not include that kind of thing??

Comment: For conciseness.  There's nothing really bad about "Thank you." or "Can anyone help?" statements, but they don't add anything either, and just mean more to read. So the general consensus has been to remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick is to make a virtual table to which you can attempt to join the the data from your logfile. In my example I've used the postgres generate_series function to generate a series of second values to append to an initial timestamp (I assume there is a similar function in MySQL?).

The trick is to use the virtual table to which to do a left join to the actual data, to find where there is a missing value in the logging table (i.e., where logger.timestamp will be NULL).

Something along these lines will show you where there is a missing timestamp if any.

```
SELECT
    y.c
    , logger.timestamp
FROM
    (SELECT 
        a +  cast(b || ' sec' as interval) as c
    FROM 
        (SELECT
               cast('2011-10-31 10:00:00' as timestamp) as a
               ,t.b from generate_series(0,100,10) as t(b)
         )x
    ) y 
    LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT timestamp from log
    ) logger ON y.c = logger.timestamp
WHERE
     logger.timestamp IS NULL;
```